# No content is displaying on the main content area

Tags: login, magento-2.1.3, parent-child-theme, luma-theme, home-page

My Homepage , Login and Create an Account pages are blank. Only the header, nav menu and footer are showing. Main content area is not showing. However, when accessing CMS about-us page the cms block content is showing. I have added my home page as the default page for my storeview.

I'm using my custom child theme from luma theme.

**My Custom theme default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" class="CustomTheme\CustomLoginHeader\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">

              <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Register</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block> 


        </block>

         <block class="CustomTheme\CustomHeaderLeft\Block\StoreManager" name="other-sites-link" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>

</referenceContainer> 
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" class="CustomTheme\CustomNavMenu\Block\Html\Topmenu" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
<move element="minicart" destination="header.links"/>
<!--<move element="store_switcher" destination ="panel.header"/>-->
<referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper"/>
</body>
</page>
```

> Version: magento CE 2.1.3 PHP: 5.6 Mode: Developer

**Edit**

Adding the System.log

```
    [2017-02-21 09:25:17] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE3_4999a55d7d9f00b9a016b5e16762ce70a and handles default, customer_account_login: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 09:25:17] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE3_40a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441 and handles 1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 09:25:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:25:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:25:17] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:25:17] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE3_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:40] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE3_431ef5d54dbe85cfa712c6b2127defaea and handles default, cms_index_index, cms_page_view, cms_index_index_id_member-home-page: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:51] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:56] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE3_40cdcf722945b22930f6ae38cf12ea6f0 and handles default, catalog_category_view, catalog_category_view_type_layered, catalog_category_view_type_layered_without_children, catalog_category_view_id_47: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 09:26:56] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE3_4a7ccd8094436548b564a588f6303121c and handles 2columns-left: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 09:59:22] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE4_4999a55d7d9f00b9a016b5e16762ce70a and handles default, customer_account_login: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 09:59:22] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE4_40a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441 and handles 1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 09:59:22] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:59:22] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:59:22] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 09:59:22] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE4_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 10:01:41] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 10:01:57] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE0_31d5ed1d21fc106e91a3b31fa91f7e26d and handles default, catalog_category_edit: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 10:01:57] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE0_3793edbdc1c00dd1c3aa9e1b3dc856b39 and handles admin-2columns-left: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-02-21 10:01:57] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-02-21 10:01:57] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-02-21 10:01:57] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2017-02-21 10:01:57] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE0_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

**Customer_account_login.xml** // vendor/magento/module_customer/view/frontend/layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
            <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="newcustomer.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Please check your logs. Also make sure you have developer mode enabled.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya: My site is already in developer mode

Comment: It looks like error in xml, please put your customer_account_login.xml file content.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya : I have updated my question with the xml. But i didn't edited that file.

Answer (score 1):

**Default Magento 2 with sample data with luma themes, Category landing page and homepage are coming from widgets.**

You can check widget from

> Content -> Elements -> Widget

There are list of widget are available here and all widget are assinged to Magento Luma Themes.

So when we create new theme, Based on parent luma theme, All sample data are missing in our new theme because widget are not set in Our custom theme.

[image]

**If you want to display content same as Luma theme, You have to create new widget same as Luma theme from widget section from admin.**

Comment: Hi Rakesh. I know this and i have already implemented all these. But i think this is due to some issues on the xml file. I have updated my question with the system.log errors. plz have a look into that. thanks